# Easiest way to implement push notification in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native, how can I create simple push notifications in react native that I can trigger with buttons (or events like websocket message) like the notifications in android studio (with title,small icon, message...) , I've seen some tutorials that I tried but don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the package named react-native-push-notification

[Package Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification)

The installation steps are quite easy. Please use the GitHub repo for getting the steps

[Github Repo](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)

Comment: Hi, do you know if it works without the manual installation (like editing the gradle file,AndroidManifest.xml,...) because I'm working with expo and I don't have these files.

Comment: a package named expo-notifications can be used in this case. It is mentioned in official expo docs